# Create query to SQL server C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have problem with field `car_brand_id`. I need this field to create relationship, but i have error in this string. How fix this problem?

```
string brand_query = "SELECT car_brand_id FROM car_brand WHERE name_brand = @brand ";
cmd = new SqlCommand(brand_query, SqlConn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@brand", brand);
int car_brand_id = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  // There i have an error



string model_query = "INSERT INTO car_model (name_model, car_brand_id) VALUES (@model, @car_brand_id)";
cmd = new SqlCommand(model_query, SqlConn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@model", model);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@car_brand_id", car_brand_id);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Error message:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constrains. "FK_car_model_car_b30F848ED". The conflict occured in db "avtoservice:, table "dbo.car_brand", column "car_brand_id". The statument has been terminated

Comment: Did you read the error message?

Comment: @SLaks The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constrains. "FK_car_model_car_b30F848ED". The conflict occured in db "avtoservice:, table "dbo.car_brand", column "car_brand_id". The statument has been terminated

Comment: Read the error message.  Your database isn't letting you insert that data.

Comment: @RickHas please the error to the post, it can be edited))

Comment: is your car_brand_id valid? Check your car_brand table data.

Comment: @R Quijano of course )

Comment: @Rocketq ok, i edit querstion

Comment: (It looks like you have an answer, so the following is academic now. However when you have an error in the future, messages are best copy and pasted, to avoid spelling errors, and to save you some time.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing this line:

```
int car_brand_id = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  // There i have an error
```

To this:

```
int car_brand_id = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

The `ExecuteNonQuery()` method will return the number of rows affected, not the value from your query, as it appears you are expecting.

Comment: Implicit conversion type " object " in the "INT" is impossible. There is a clear transformation ( possibly there is no reduction )

Comment: `int car_brand_id = (int) cmd.ExecuteScalar();`

Comment: Yes, you will need to cast it to `int` as @JaredMoore stated.  I will fix the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

Parameters should not be in quotes.

That's a string that literally says `@brand`, not the value of the parameter.